# get values from an array depending on other value PHP

Tags: php, arrays

here's the result of my array

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => ABC
        [1] => abc
        [2] => rodriguez
        [3] => Barkleys, 15 NO.
        [4] => A
        [5] => 1234567890
        [6] => 
        [7] => YES
        [8] => a
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => DEF
        [1] => def
        [2] => DAM
        [3] => Barkleys, 15 NO.
        [4] => A
        [5] => 1234567891
        [6] => 
        [7] => YES
        [8] => b
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => GHI
        [1] => ghi
        [2] => TEG
        [3] => Street4
        [4] => B
        [5] => 1234567892
        [6] => YES
        [7] => 
        [8] => c
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => JKL
        [1] => jkl
        [2] => CHA
        [3] => Street4
        [4] => B
        [5] => 1234567893
        [6] => YES
        [7] => 
        [8] => d
    )


   )
```

I need some of values from this array by using other value for exp. if I have value of 4th index in two separate arrays.

```
array ( 
        [0] =>  A 
        [1] =>  A
      )
array (
        [0] =>  B 
        [1] =>  B
      )
```

Now I need to get values of 2nd index in two seperate array using above two array value

```
array (
         [1] =>  rodriguez
         [2] =>  DAM
      )
array ( 
         [1] =>  TEG 
         [2] =>  CHA
      )
```

How can I do this please suggest solution.

Comment: On what condition you want to break to two different arrays?

Comment: Actually I want to sort 4th index first then sort 2nd index basis on every value of 4th index.

Comment: I think you got me @Naincy ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this way :

```
<?php

$firstArray = array();
foreach($bigArray as $key => $array) {
    $value = $array[4]; //fetch the 4th indice
    if(! isset($firstArray[$value])) {
        $firstArray[$value] = array();
    }

    $firstArray[$value][$key] = $value;
}

$secondArray = array();
foreach($firstArray as $name => $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $info) {
        $value = $bigArray[$key][2]; //fetch the 2nd indice

        if(! isset($secondArray[$value])) {
            $secondArray[$value] = array();
        }

        $secondArray[$value][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to get array values on the basis of first one @Guillaume

Comment: What's wrong with my solution ? Replace $yourBigarray by the name of your variable and try it ;-)

Comment: Your solution is just give index values from big array but i need 2nd array from value of first array

Comment: Okay, i just updated my answer. Hope this will help !

Comment: Nop @Guillaume : (

Comment: What's wrong with this solution ? What result do you have and what do you want?